# Using NSURL with a PHP Web Service that uses a brackets in its get request

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I am writing an iPhone application that needs to get data from a web service.  In this service, there is a possibility of the same variable having multiple values, and this variable is accessed using [ ] brackets.  (I am not a PHP developer, but I understand this scheme is not uncommon for PHP services.)

So a sample request might look like:

> example.com/service.php?id[]=1&id[]=2

The code I am using to form the URL looks like this:

```
NSString *string = @"http://example.com/service.php?id[]=1&id[]=2";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSMutableURLRequest *networkRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
...
```

The problem is that, after the second line, the URL is automatically encoded, so that the URL is really tries to access looks like this:

> example.com/service.php?id%5B%5D=1&id%5B%5D=2

As a result, my request does not access the information I want.  Is there a way to prevent NSURL from encoding my URL so that it can access this web service?

Comment: I'm really surprised that the web server doesn't accept the url-escaped string; what NSURL is doing is proper web behavior, those square brackets aren't supposed to sit unchanged across the web. Are you absolutely certain that the request will work properly if you, for example, paste the unescaped version in your browser (where, again, it should escape them). Do you have it working unescaped somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it turned out that communication with the service owner revealed irregular behavior on the server that caused the problem, but I was attributing it to NSURL's handling of strings.  My apologizes, and thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I was having such issue in my application, I solved by encoding my url string before construction of the url. So I think u need to do it like this

```
NSString *string = @"http://example.com/service.php?id%5B%5D=1&id%5B%5D=2";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSMutableURLRequest *networkRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Please refer the [link](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) for more ifno.

Comment: Then u need to encode the entire url, as I encoded it. I will get following url string `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fservice.php%3Fid%5B%5D%3D1%26id%5B%5D%3D2`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simply escape them:

```
NSString *string = @"http://example.com/service.php?id\[\]=1&id\[\]=2";
```

It's possible that it will just end up URLEncoding the backslashes, too, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I did try this before I posted the question, but it didn't work.